# Why does VS-Code Autopep8 format 2 white lines?

Tags: python, format, autopep8

```
print("Hello")

def world():
    print("Hello")

world()
```

Gets corrected to:

```
print("Hello")


def world():
    print("Hello")


world()
```

I have tried to:

- Reinstall Virtual Studio Code
- Reinstall Python 3.8
- Computer Reboot
- Using other formatters like Black and yapf but got the same result

Comment: PEP8 [States to](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines) `Surround top-level function and class definitions with two blank lines`. Since your statements are top-level, they get corrected to match that design recommendation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because auto**pep8** follows [**PEP8**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines) which suggests 2 blank lines around top-level functions.

> Surround top-level function and class definitions with two blank lines.

Answer (score 8):

You can disable this by using the following configuration in your `.vscode/settings.json`

```json
{
    "python.formatting.provider": "autopep8",
    "python.formatting.autopep8Args": [
        "--ignore=E302"
    ]
}
```

Here are all the `autopep8` features explained: https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8#features

Comment: while the link to GitHub is OK, it would be useful to include relevant aspects (as a quotation) in your answer

Answer (score 0):

you can also configure `python.formatting.autopep8Args` under your vscode setting.

[image: python.formatting.autopep8Args]

Comment: Configure it how? I added `--ignore=E302` but it doesn't prevent it spacing everything in double lines when saving.

Comment: @Hasen Not sure why it is not working for you but you can check https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8 for more information.